# Does MLKit barcode reader solved native crash issue that was present on Mobile Vision API barcode scanner?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I was using Mobile Vision API to detect barcodes using a camera stream, just like in this example: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader, unfortunately there is an issue in which the app crash out of the blue due to a null pointer dereference in the barcode reader's native code, see [issue #351](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/351).

Although the reported issue is on a Pixel device I found the same stacktrace on my Samsung Tab A devices running from Android 7 and 8, here is the stacktrace of the error

```
 Build fingerprint: 'samsung/gta2xlltespr/gta2xlltespr:8.1.0/M1AJQ/T597PVPU1ASA2:user/release-keys'
03-13 15:42:47.077 F/DEBUG   (11969): Revision: '7'
03-13 15:42:47.077 F/DEBUG   (11969): ABI: 'arm'
03-13 15:42:47.078 F/DEBUG   (11969): pid: 11696, tid: 11874, name: Thread-24 03-13 15:42:47.078 F/DEBUG   (11969): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xc
03-13 15:42:47.078 F/DEBUG   (11969): Cause: null pointer dereference
03-13 15:42:47.078 F/DEBUG   (11969):     r0 ea09c5a8  r1 a25b973a  r2 ea09b6d0  r3 00000000
03-13 15:42:47.078 F/DEBUG   (11969):     r4 00000000  r5 ea09b6d0  r6 c7b967f0  r7 c7b96904
03-13 15:42:47.078 F/DEBUG   (11969):     r8 00000022  r9 00000001  sl 43dc8000  fp 44518000
03-13 15:42:47.078 F/DEBUG   (11969):     ip eb2b3d58  sp c7b967e0  lr eb28a345  pc c8951c12  cpsr 200d0030
03-13 15:42:47.080 F/DEBUG   (11969): 
03-13 15:42:47.080 F/DEBUG   (11969): backtrace:
03-13 15:42:47.080 F/DEBUG   (11969):     #00 pc 00011c12  /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_vision/barcode/libs/armeabi-v7a/libbarhopper.so
03-13 15:42:47.080 F/DEBUG   (11969):     #01 pc 0000a345  /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_vision/barcode/libs/armeabi-v7a/libbarhopper.so
03-13 15:42:47.080 F/DEBUG   (11969):     #02 pc 0000331d  /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_vision/barcode/libs/armeabi-v7a/libbarhopper.so
03-13 15:42:47.080 F/DEBUG   (11969):     #03 pc 000043df  /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_vision/barcode/libs/armeabi-v7a/libbarhopper.so
03-13 15:42:47.081 F/DEBUG   (11969):     #04 pc 00001e63  /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_vision/barcode/libs/armeabi-v7a/libbarhopper.so
03-13 15:42:47.081 F/DEBUG   (11969):     #05 pc 00002a91  /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_vision/barcode/libs/armeabi-v7a/libbarhopper.so
03-13 15:42:47.081 F/DEBUG   (11969):     #06 pc 00000adf  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000034/oat/arm/DynamiteModulesA.odex (offset 0x6000)
```

This is an important feature in my current app and would really appreciate if someone can tell me if it's safe to use MLKit.

Answer (score 0):

`SIGSEGV` alias `11` means segmentation fault; memory address `0xc` not mapped to object; [siginfo.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/asm-generic/siginfo.h) defines that and this is caused by accessing an address which had not been allocated (it's almost the same as an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in `Java`, but on the memory allocation level).

the example app uses hopelessly outdated dependencies. better try the current version:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2"
```

it's difficult to tell if this is "save", because the question does not feature the least code - nor does it tell which version of the library you use. so that's nothing one could reproduce in a reliable manner.

Comment: I forgot to add but I'm using this version of Google Play Services

On build.gradle

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'`

On app/build.gradle
`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2'`